# XMLHttpRequest setRequestHeader for each request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

The following code automatically sets `Authorization request header` for all jQuery Ajax requests:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + jwtoken);
    }
});
```

I want something like above for all `XMLHttpRequest` objects created manually. More exactly the below request hasn't set `Authorization header`.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.file = $('myfile')[0].files[0];
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('fileId', fileId);
xhr.open('post','my-rote', true)
xhr.send(fd);
```

I don't want to use `xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + jwtoken);` beacuse when I create `XMLHttpRequest` objects the variable `jwtoken` is already deleted.

Comment: if you create that manually, you are the only one controlling the creation process. when using jQuery, the request is created by the framework so it can give you the infrastructure to automatically set up the header. when you are in control, you should take the responsibility and set up the infrastructure for header injection. the one and only answer does exactly that - so mark it as answer.

Answer (score 23):

One way is to create a closure and pass the jwtoken to it when it is available. You can use the method returned by the closure to create a XMLHttpRequest object.

```
var customXMLHttpRequest = (function (jwtoken) {

    function getXMLHttpRequest(method, url, async){
        var xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttpRequest.open(method, url, async);
        xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + jwtoken);
        return xmlHttpRequest;
    }

    return getXMLHttpRequest;
})('Your token');
```

Here is how you can use this method to get a new XMLHttpRequest object.

```
var xmlHttpRequest = customXMLHttpRequest('post','http://www.yoursite.com',true);
```

This object will have the header set.

Another option is to save the token in the cookie and when creating XMLHttpRequest, use this value after retrieving it from cookie.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me. But I thought  that it is possible to use something similar to `$.ajaxSetup beforeSend`.